# Test for window existence before posting a message vs let PostMessage fail: Which of them has less overhead?

Tags: performance, winapi, hook, overhead

I have to install some Window Hooks in order to monitor MOUSE messages for a limited number of processes.

As these processes are under my control I could make them collaborate, so I chose to code a simple DLL that installs a **local** `WH_MOUSE` hook, and the Hook procedure does a `PostMessage` to a specific Window Handle in a "controller" process.
This DLL will be loaded by each process I must monitor.

This way I don't need Low Level Hooks, Global Hooks or dll injection techniques.

Now I'm looking for maximum performance:
In the Hook Procedure, after message filtering I have to call `PostMessage` with a destination Handle that could *potentially* be invalid.
I can see 3 options:

1. Test everytime for `if (IsWindow(myHWnd))`: I think this puts an overhead on the hooked processes
2. Don't test, and let `PostMessage` gently fail: does this put any overhead on the entire system in case of failure?
3. Don't worry about that and go for (2) because hooking mouse messages IS itself the biggest overhead.

What do you think about that?
Thank you

Comment: Optimizing a program for a condition that's actually a major mishap makes no sense.  The host quit without unregistering the hook, that's bad.  Also the reason you should not use PostMessage(), it can fail for multiple reasons, you can get a more reliable error from a named pipe.  It is a lot faster too, although you'd never noticed this for events that run at human-time.

Comment: Thank you Hans. Each host process is guaranteed to unregister its own hook (I didn't focus on details for sake of simplicity), and reliability is not an issue here: my goal is to calculate if a group of gui processes don't get any user action for some time, so I think a loose-coupling, light-weight message approach is precisely what I need. I agree that the main issue here is the hooking itself, but I have no alternatives, so I'm wondering if I can make it as optimized as possible ;-)

Comment: `2` is the only safe option: With option `1` you introduce a [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) race condition. The call to `IsWindow` may return `TRUE`, but by the time you call `PostMessage`, the window may be gone already.

Comment: @IInspectable: you caught me... ;-) This was a serious oversight by my side. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Depending on what exactly you are monitoring, you might consider simply getting rid of the WH_MOUSE hooks altogether and let the controller monitor the mouse directly instead, via the Raw Input API.

Comment: +1 for Raw Input. I completely forgot it. Maybe it's a bit overkill  in this particular case.  My goal is to calculate if a group of gui processes don't get any "user action" for some time, and with "user action" I mean keystrokes or mouseclicks/wheel - NOT mouse move. My dll acts as an "agent" that notifies me about user actions occurred in the specific processes who loaded it.